# Excluding standard directories from code coverage results with C++/CLI

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, c++-cli, code-coverage

I have a Visual Studio 2010 .NET 4 solution with C# projects and a C++/CLI project.

I use Visual Studio's built in unit tests and code coverage.

Other than the fact that Visual Studio 2010 coverage tool for C++/CLI projects seems to be much weaker than Visual Studio 2008 coverage tool, I get weird results.

For example, I get uncovered code in this file:

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring

And some other files in that directory.

I want to exclude this code from coverage results.

Is there a way to put some [exclude attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.excludefromcodecoverageattribute.aspx) on that code?
If not, is there a different automatic way to exclude that code from coverage? If not, is there a way to use [EXCLUDE option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182402%28VS.80%29.aspx) to exclude it? Can it be done automatically within Visual Studio without running the coverage tool from command prompt?

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the MSDN documentation you linked to says:

> EXCLUDE option is supported with code coverage.
>
> To exclude all functions in a namespace use the wildcard character:
>
> MyNamespace::*

Have you tried `/EXCLUDE:std::*` ?  It sounds as if that would be the way to go.

Comment: How exactly do I add this option to the build process? How do I control on how vsinstr is invoked?

Comment: Have you tried on the Analyze menu -> Configure Code Analysis (for Solution | for <projectname>)?

Comment: code coverage settings can't be found in code analysis settings. Am I missing something?